# error using swank with leiningen and elein

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen, swank, clojurebox

I'm using leiningen and elein in linux, when I create my project I add:

```
:dev-dependencies [[swank-clojure "1.2.1"]])
```

then I call "elein-swank" and perfect...this connects swank and (apparently) slime because the repl opens and I can work with my code.

Now I've installed clojure box on windows; this includes clojure-mode and slime, and I've downloaded leiningen and elein mode.

I create my project, add the swank dependencie and when I call "elein-swank" this shows me:

> "No swank found.."

And the elein-swank buffer says

> Connection opened on localhost port 4005.

Apparently swank didn't work because if I call slime-connect and try to use the 4005 port this opens the repl but if I press enter it says "connection close"

Then I tried to download swank-clojure using:

> lein plugin install swank-clojure 1.3.3

I've read that this way is obsolete and now leiningen includes swank (correct me if I wrong).  I try use swank then and this doesn't work either.

What can I do?

Comment: I would suggest using swank-clojure with clojure-jack-in. https://github.com/technomancy/swank-clojure

Comment: To use the newer swank-clojure, just open project.clj (or any clojure file in your project) in emacs and then call M-x clojure-jack-in